# Tezos Node syncing very slow. 40K block in 24 hours

Tags: node

My Tezos node is syncing very slowly.. In 24 hours only 40K blocks got synced.
                                                                                                 Is it because of DISK IO or RAM or something else??
Attaching logs below.

`Jan 25 22:21:58 - validator.block: Block BLfJc2QPwWtSK3vrwwtZfiLGf6aR8ACuDpfTxG5w1SePaMnFHTc successfully validated
Jan 25 22:21:58 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:21:56-00:00, treated in 18.939us, completed in 2.102s
Jan 25 22:21:58 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.PsddFKi32cMJ: switching to new head BLfJc2QPwWtSK3vrwwtZfiLGf6aR8ACuDpfTxG5w1SePaMnFHTc
Jan 25 22:21:58 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.PsddFKi32cMJ:  Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:21:58-00:00, treated in 3.701ms, completed in 266ms
Jan 25 22:21:58 - validator.chain: Update current head to BLfJc2QPwWtSK3vrwwtZfiLGf6aR8ACuDpfTxG5w1SePaMnFHTc (fitness 00::0000000000b20233), same branch
Jan 25 22:21:58 - validator.chain: Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:21:58-00:00, treated in 21.12ms, completed in 296ms
Jan 25 22:22:02 - validator.block: Block BMaQsx1mXUeWJt6KJzrPFkMXnANuPPFS8rECzMvs5RvTN1PDtXL successfully validated
Jan 25 22:22:02 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:21:58-00:00, treated in 25.614us, completed in 4.249s
Jan 25 22:22:03 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.PsddFKi32cMJ: switching to new head BMaQsx1mXUeWJt6KJzrPFkMXnANuPPFS8rECzMvs5RvTN1PDtXL
Jan 25 22:22:03 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.PsddFKi32cMJ:  Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:22:03-00:00, treated in 3.702ms, completed in 279ms
Jan 25 22:22:03 - validator.chain: Update current head to BMaQsx1mXUeWJt6KJzrPFkMXnANuPPFS8rECzMvs5RvTN1PDtXL (fitness 00::0000000000b20254), same branch
Jan 25 22:22:03 - validator.chain: Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:22:02-00:00, treated in 20.683ms, completed in 495ms
Jan 25 22:22:06 - validator.block: Block BKp7rDYZZte2CdwFQ8gzqHdopR6GRkfmnFrhetKyM94aXsmXJo4 successfully validated
Jan 25 22:22:06 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:22:03-00:00, treated in 23.868us, completed in 3.513s
Jan 25 22:22:07 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.PsddFKi32cMJ: switching to new head BKp7rDYZZte2CdwFQ8gzqHdopR6GRkfmnFrhetKyM94aXsmXJo4
Jan 25 22:22:07 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.PsddFKi32cMJ:  Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:22:07-00:00, treated in 8.991ms, completed in 242ms
Jan 25 22:22:07 - validator.chain: Update current head to BKp7rDYZZte2CdwFQ8gzqHdopR6GRkfmnFrhetKyM94aXsmXJo4 (fitness 00::0000000000b20275), same branch
Jan 25 22:22:07 - validator.chain: Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:22:06-00:00, treated in 18.685ms, completed in 499ms
Jan 25 22:22:11 - validator.block: Block BM1iNWHhfnURo1NwX8yHtcQPWVxvnsur6yMMpNttkkBxYKiGP84 successfully validated
Jan 25 22:22:11 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:22:07-00:00, treated in 23.24us, completed in 4.343s
Jan 25 22:22:11 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.PsddFKi32cMJ: switching to new head BM1iNWHhfnURo1NwX8yHtcQPWVxvnsur6yMMpNttkkBxYKiGP84
Jan 25 22:22:11 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.PsddFKi32cMJ:  Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:22:11-00:00, treated in 3.173ms, completed in 254ms
Jan 25 22:22:11 - validator.chain: Update current head to BM1iNWHhfnURo1NwX8yHtcQPWVxvnsur6yMMpNttkkBxYKiGP84 (fitness 00::0000000000b20296), same branch
Jan 25 22:22:11 - validator.chain: Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:22:11-00:00, treated in 20.781ms, completed in 298ms
Jan 25 22:22:15 - validator.block: Block BKqZ2oPMBNpw84vUmADitWzcY5UVmMu3T1Tx2WL9YzWm7EruefS successfully validated
Jan 25 22:22:15 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:22:11-00:00, treated in 25.45us, completed in 3.253s
Jan 25 22:22:15 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.PsddFKi32cMJ: switching to new head BKqZ2oPMBNpw84vUmADitWzcY5UVmMu3T1Tx2WL9YzWm7EruefS
Jan 25 22:22:15 - prevalidator.NetXdQprcVkpa.PsddFKi32cMJ:  Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:22:15-00:00, treated in 1.981ms, completed in 271ms
Jan 25 22:22:15 - validator.chain: Update current head to BKqZ2oPMBNpw84vUmADitWzcY5UVmMu3T1Tx2WL9YzWm7EruefS (fitness 00::0000000000b202b7), same branch
Jan 25 22:22:15 - validator.chain: Request pushed on 2020-01-25T22:22:15-00:00, treated in 24.265ms, completed in 299ms`

Comment: Can you give more details about your setup ? Seems like you are having a pure support issue so perhaps asking on TG or baking slack would be more efficient ?

Comment: I am not interested in baking. I have a wallet use case so I use this docker image present on docker hub here. https://hub.docker.com/layers/tezos/tezos/mainnet/images/sha256-6cf4a0336eb600d55139560cc4d4db99d6aff48d84dccc608f4951e0bf46fb08                              I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Digital Ocean instance ( 32 GB Memory / 640 GB Disk + 1.95 TB / SFO2). I am also running other nodes on the same instance in docker.

Comment: what history mode you are choosing ?

Answer (score 1):

Your machine should be fine. 2 CPU with 8GB of ram and a SSD is plenty enough for a node.

40k/24h is indeed a bit slow. It usually takes around a week to bootstrap on a regular machine (maybe ~4 days on a dedicated and powerful one). As the bootstrap phase is IOs (disk) intensive, it could be disk congestion as you run multiple nodes on a virtual instance. You should monitoring you disk usage.

Otherwise, you should consider using storage snapshots to set up a node (see http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/snapshots.html)